# Nvidia Geforce MX150 not working on Unbuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04

My dedicated video card is not used on any program i try.

I tried to :
-Select it through prime, it selects it but still not used.

-Re-install nvidia drivers (using nvidia-drivers-525) (multiple times)

-Disabling secure boot

It is actually detected as 3D controller.

`lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d" 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] 02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev ff)`

And in my log when i try to use it through prime I have this message :

```
Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
NVRM: This is a 64-bit BAR mapped above 4GB by the system
NVRM: BIOS or the Linux kernel, but the PCI bridge
NVRM: immediately upstream of this GPU does not define
NVRM: a matching prefetchable memory window.
```

If anyone has any idea, thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

There was an urgent need of my graphic card so i switched over to windows and the card worked, I accepted one proposition that i never seen before to make it more visible for people with same problem **BUT I DIDN'T TESTED IT**.